# Running out of memory with Java WebStart

Tags: java, jasper-reports, reporting, ireport, java-web-start

I have a java application that usually gets run using java webstart. Right now when I run a certain Jasper report from my application I get an out of memory exception, but only when the application is run using webstart. When I run my application from my local machine, not using webstart, the out of memory exception doesn't happen.

Some of the things I've done is tried moving all the subreports from header and footer bands to detail bands (using iReport). I've also made sure that cache is being used in all the subreports. What else can I do in this case to get this memory exception to stop happening in the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to define more memory in your jnlp file:

```
 <j2se version="1.4+" java-vm-args="-Xms256M -Xmx512M"/>
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources).

Comment: Better to use `<j2se version="1.3" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="128m"/>` which is easier to validate.